# Reactivemongo TTL collections

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I know I can set TTL in MongoDB with

```
db.ttl_collection.ensureIndex( { "Date": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 } )
```

and I know I can ensure index with Scala in Reactivemongo with

```
collection.indexesManager.ensure(index)
```

But how can I set TTL collections in reactivemongo from code?
Or is there any other way to make expiring records in Mongo with reactivemongo in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it out. It's not really clear way to do it but seems to work:

```
collection.indexesManager.ensure(Index(Seq(("Date", IndexType(BSONInteger(1)))), Some("expireAfterSeconds"), false, false, false, false, None, BSONDocument( "expireAfterSeconds" -> 0 )
```

This way every object with expireAfterSeconds: BSONDateTime in this collection will expire after the date specified
But I don't even know what these booleans are responsible for.

Comment: I'm guessing "Date" is the name of your field in the document, right? Do you need to do anything else in order to get it working? I added this on my code and the document is not expiring. Should this be called at initialization or before every insert?

Answer (score 1):

On my project we have this function

```
  def ensureIndex(
               key: List[(String, IndexType)],
               name: Option[String] = None,
               unique: Boolean = false,
               background: Boolean = false,
               dropDups: Boolean = false,
               sparse: Boolean = false,
               version: Option[Int] = None,
               options: BSONDocument = BSONDocument()) = {

  val index = Index(key, name, unique, background, dropDups, sparse, version, options)
  log.info(s"Ensuring index: $index")
  collection.indexesManager.ensure(index)
}
```

And I use it like the following for TTL indexes (`$doc` comes from the BSON DSL):

```
ensureIndex(List("lastModifiedOn" -> IndexType.Ascending), options = $doc("expireAfterSeconds" -> 30))
```